# Cudnn files are not recognized although are present

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, cudnn

I created a virtualenv and installed TensorFlow 2.4.0. The CUDA was already installed so I tried  to install Cudnn according to these instructions

```
$ tar -xzvf cudnn-11.0-linux-x64-v8.0.2.39.tgz

$ sudo cp cuda/include/cudnn*.h /usr/local/cuda/include
$ sudo cp cuda/lib64/libcudnn* /usr/local/cuda/lib64
$ sudo chmod a+r /usr/local/cuda/include/cudnn*.h /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudnn*
```

Indeed after the installation files were installed to these paths /usr/local/cuda/include and /usr/local/cuda/lib64 .This was the result ( a fracture of the list)

[image]

Although the file 'libcudnn.so.8' is present ,it doesnt recognize it
[image]

Should I copy the files to another folder due to the created virtual environment?
What does light green file indicate??

Comment: Is /usr/local/cuda/lib64 in your library paths? For example in LD_LIBRARY_PATH, most likely it isnot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just simply added this in .bashrc

```
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-11.0/bin:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-11.0/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

according to this
[Installing the NVIDIA driver, CUDA and cuDNN on Linux (Ubuntu 20.04)](https://gist.github.com/kmhofmann/cee7c0053da8cc09d62d74a6a4c1c5e4)